# установка cookies в selenium webdriver firefox c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

сохраняю cookies с прошлого захода

```
 ReadOnlyCollection<OpenQA.Selenium.Cookie> cookies = driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies;
```

загружаю

```
driver2.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
driver2.Url = "http://samy.pl/evercookie/";

foreach (var cookie in cookies)
    driver2.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(cookie);
```

Вылазит ошибка в строке  `driver2.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(cookie);` - `InvalidCookieDomainError is not defined`, домен тот же. Загружал и до  `driver2.Url` но тщетно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методом проб и ошибок нашел ответ, но вот действует он только после `driver2.Url =`    и куки появятся после обновления страницы :(

```
foreach (var cookie in cookies)
    {
    OpenQA.Selenium.Cookie name = new OpenQA.Selenium.Cookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value);
    driver2.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(name);
    }
```